# Calling different tabs from normal activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs, tabbar

in my app after the SplashScreen i am calling a Tabactivity.

In tha tab activity, from the first tab i am switched over to a another activity called as Float, which is not related to the TabActivity. From this activity when a condition becomes True i want to show the third tab in the TabBar. How to open the third tab from the tab activity.

Following is the code of my Tabactivity class

```
public class MainTabBar extends TabActivity 
{
    TabHost tabHost;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.maintab);


          addTab1(Display.class);
          addTab2(History.class); 
          addTab3(Capture    .class);
          addTab4(AboutUs.class);
    }

    private void addTab1( Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");  

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.hometab, getTabWidget(), false);
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    private void addTab2( Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2");  

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.macstab, getTabWidget(), false);
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    private void addTab3( Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3");  

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.abouttab, getTabWidget(), false);        
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

    private void addTab4( Class<?> c)
    {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4");  

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.contacttab, getTabWidget(), false);      
        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Is it to the above thing using a flag or any other easy way, pls suggest me friends, i am very new to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tab index to show the third tab

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```